# Typhoon using storyboard with view controller initializers

Tags: dependency-injection, storyboard, typhoon

I want to use storyboards to create a view controller named "child", so I define:

```
- (TyphoonStoryboard *)storyBoard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:@"Storyboard"];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton; //Let's make this a singleton
    }];
}

- (ChildViewController *)childViewControllerFromStoryboard
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withFactory:self.storyBoard selector:@selector(instantiateInitialViewController)];
}
```

I'll have a root view controller that will contain the child view controller

```
- (RootViewController *)rootViewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[RootViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithChildViewController:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self.childViewControllerFromStoryboard];
        }];
    }]; 
}
```

The last part is just to inject the dependencies for the child view controller:

```
- (ChildViewController *)childViewController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ChildViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        // Initilization doesn't work.
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithData:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self.data];
        }];
        // Property injection does.
        // [definition injectProperty:@selector(data)]
    }];
}
```

Super normal, I'm just using its initializator but it never gets called. I think it's because `initWithCoder:` is always used, the one designated for storyboards.

Questions:

1. Is possible to use view controller initializers with storyboards? It looks like no, similar to appDelegate.
2. Is this the simplest approach to use storyboards directly from the assembly?
3. If I have several storyboards, is there a way of defining the storyboards parametrically? I don't want to end up with something like `storyBoard1, storyBoard2, ..., storyBoardN`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Typhoon!

> 1. Is possible to use view controller initializers with storyboards? It looks like no, similar to appDelegate.

No, you cannot init object twice (you can call `init` method twice but it's odd and incorrect and can be cause of errors).

Each UIViewController and UIView created from Xib/Storyboard uses `initWithCoder:` initialization method.

Instead you can use *method injections* and inject `setData:` or use property injection.

> 2. Is this the simplest approach to use storyboards directly from the assembly?

No. Simplest approach is using plist bootstrapping. (When initial storyboard name specified in the Info.plist)

Check guide here:

https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Obtaining-Built-Components#first-bootstrap-typhoon-using-either

But if you have more that one storyboard, then you can specify initial in the plist, and other in assembly.

> 3. If I have several storyboards, is there a way of defining the storyboards parametrically? I don't want to end up with something like storyBoard1, storyBoard2, ..., storyBoardN.

Yes, you can use *runtime arguments* typhoon feature for that.
Using runtime arguments your definition becomes to

```
- (TyphoonStoryboard *)storyBoardWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:name]; // <-- runtime argument injection
            [initializer injectParameterWith:self];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];
     }];
}
```

Is it what you asking for?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! About the answers:
1. Totally ok with that.
2. I'm already using the plist but still I have to create a root VC that will contain the VCs from the storyboards.
3. I've tried it but it raises an exception in `validateScope` saying "The runtime arguments injections are only applicable to prototype and object-graph scoped definitions, but is set for definition: TyphoonStoryboard"

Comment: 2. Are you using plist for storyboard (UIMainStoryboardFile plist key)? In that case root view controller set automatically.
3. Correct. Are you sure that you need singletone here? Storyboard already retained by viewControllers produced from it.

Comment: 2. Right, but root view controller in my case is a custom view controller without a storyboard. 3. After removing the singleton scope I receive an error in `doRegistration` "Key 'storyboardWithName:' is already registered"

Comment: I think the error in 3. it's because it's declared in the assembly and then is called from another definition `return [self storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"]` in the same assembly.

Comment: Yes. You cannot return same definition object twice in two assembly methods (or more). Each method must return new definition object. Maybe we should fix that, since it can be usefull with runtime arguments.. (it's old exception)

Comment: Added feature request for that:
https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/272

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the code for the storyboard definitions I end up adding a category to `TyphoonDefinition` like:

```
@implementation TyphoonDefinition (Storyboard)

+ (TyphoonStoryboard *)withStoryboardName:(NSString *)storyboardName factory:(TyphoonComponentFactory *)factory
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[TyphoonStoryboard class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(storyboardWithName:factory:bundle:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
            [initializer injectParameterWith:storyboardName];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:factory];
            [initializer injectParameterWith:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        }];
        definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton; //Let's make this a singleton
    }];
}

@end
```

Because this is outside the assembly it doesn't register more than once.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that for the factory parameter, you would just pass in `self`?